# tracking "add a tab" page installs on other pages

Tags: facebook-page

We have a public page on our product service page http://www.facebook.com/realestateagentdirectory?sk=app_171700809577806 that allows anyone to add our "find an agent" app to their own page.

Is there a way to know when FB users install our app on their own FB pages - via page or app insights, or in a different way? Right now we have no clue who/when adds our app to their page.

One way that would work, obviously, (which would be an overkill for this and it would require users to install another app, etc.) is to do this (installing/adding a tab on your page) from within another app which keeps track of all tab additions to other pages.

But we're looking for an easier way of knowing this data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can track first visit to [Page Tab Application](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) canvas via parsing signed_request argument to collect pages who had installed application.

Later you can use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) table [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) checking for has_added_app field to ensure tab is installed/removed

Comment: Thanks Juicy. We'll have to do that I guess. But you don't know of any "automated" way for us to know that - like via insights, etc?